# IBM Domino Send reminder to another user

Tags: java, lotus-domino, alarm, agent

From user A's mailbox application, can an agent send reminder to another user B?

I coded a (Java) agent, which runs within user A's mailbox to create reminder for user A him/herself. This works.

If I replace

```
reminderDocument.save();
reminderDocument.putInFolder("$Alarms");
```

with

```
reminderDocument.replaceItemValue("SendTo", recipient);
reminderDocument.send();
```

then
the reminder is sent to User B. However, the alarm notification doesn't appear because this document is not part of User B's $Alarms folder. Is there a solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Sending" a reminder will always have the recipient do something with the reminder for it to become an alarm.
Please check the [Calendaring and Scheduling Schema](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc)
for how to do it "right".

If you need to place an alarm in another users inbox, without him to interact, then you need to create the document there directly and put it in his "alarm"- folder, or you have to setup "automatic processing" in the recipients mailbox (what he probably does not want).

In short: There is no easy way to do this without following the "workflow" (see Page 3 of linked document